# CNMarkPortalOnline return NG

Tags: iphone, captivenetwork

I tried to use CaptiveNetwork in order to replace the web sheet that for user authentication with the network. 
And succussfully registered the common hotspot with CNSetSupportedSSIDs in AppDelegate of my app.
However after the user authentication in my app, CNMarkPortalOnline return NG.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Below is my source code:

```
NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces(); 
NSLog(@"ifs: %@", [ifs objectAtIndex:0]);
CNMarkPortalOnline((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)[ifs objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

what are the code for CNSetSupportedSSIDs? there is a coffee bar near me. I met the inconvient too and are looking for a solution.

Comment: Dear Sun Liang:  NSString *values[] = {@"testhotspot"}; CFArrayRef arrayRef = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (void *)values, (CFIndex)1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks); if( CNSetSupportedSSIDs(arrayRef)) { NSLog(@"Successfully registered supported network SSIDs"); } else { NSLog(@"Error: Failed to register supported network SSIDs"); } <code> the login page is blocked but my application will not be called. woule you please help me?

Comment: Dear Sun Liang, would you help me?

Comment: I called "CNSetSupportedSSIDs" in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the AppDelegate, hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I am bout to make the same thing, please would you let me know if the user need to select the wifiSSID first in Wifi Settings ? Or it can simply launch the app, and if SSID is not detected by iOS, the user will be alerted "the wifi is not there" ? Brief, do you need to select Wifi first ? Much thanks.

Comment: I am bout to make the same thing, please would you let me know if the user need to select the wifiSSID first in Wifi Settings ? Or it can simply launch the app, and if SSID is not detected by iOS, the user will be alerted "the wifi is not there" ? Brief, do you need to select Wifi first ? Much thanks.